# Future Retro Achievement does not activate

Tags: achievements, fallout-4

I played the Red Menace game in Vault 111 and the Grognak game on my PipBoy, but didn't get the achievement, is there any way to get the achievement if it's not giving it to me now?

I've attempted to restart Fallout 4, restart Steam, even attempt to get it on a different character, but no luck. I know that for certain games you can delete the achievements folder and then verify the integrity of the game cache, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: I'm pretty far in the game (I have a feeling almost done with it), so I'm not sure what quest you're talking about. Red Menace and Grognak the Barbarian and the Ruby Ruins both don't work, so it's an issue of multiple of the games not triggering the achievement. I am connected to Steam and online.

Comment: Checking in again, it silently gave me the achievement last night, but I wasn't able to detect why it chose to give me it now and not when I immediately played the terminal game. Maybe some combination of restarting Steam and Fallout.